# Sending a function to another function as a parameter

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I want to send a `func` as a parameter to another `func` but I know how to do it only in case the `func` being sent has an input and an output parameters:

```
aFunc (sentFunc: Int -> String) {
    ...
}
```

But I want to achieve something like the following code where the function being sent does not have parameters:

```
func firstFunc(<i want to declare paramenter for a function here that itself does not have any parameters>) {
    if (servicedCities != nil) {
        <execute sent fuction>
    } else {
        objectMapper().getServicedCitiesifAvailable()
        <execute sent fuction>
    }
}
```

the `func` calling the above `func` should look like

```
func  secondFunc() {
    func myNestedFunction() {
        ....
    }
    ....
    firstFunc(myNestedFunction())
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func firstFunc(passedFunc:()->()) {
    passedFunc()
}

func secondFunc() {
    func myNestedFunction() {
        print("hi")
    }

    firstFunc(myNestedFunction)
}

secondFunc()
```

will ouput

> hi

in the context of the `firstFunc` call.

Note that you have to omit the `()` in the last line after the `myNestedFunction` because you dont want to call the method but pass the method itself.

Comment: What is the role of the secondFunc in your example?

Comment: @user523234 originally I wanted just to keep everything as close to his question as possible, apparently I did mess some things up, changed the code a bit - is it clearer now?

Comment: I like your answer/explanation.  That was the reason why I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
func firstFunc(sentFunc: () -> ()) {
    sentFunc()
}
```

or

```
func firstFunc(sentFunc: Void -> Void) {
    sentFunc()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Swift closures.

Check this [Swift closures and functions](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/)

```
func someFunc(paramFunc: () -> ()) {
    paramFunc()
}
```

...

```
self.someFunc { () -> () in
    //Do some code here;
}
```